# Step on the proof of proposition equivalent to quadratic reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The book "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$" has the following proposition, which leaves the last step as an exercise:

[image]

How can $(-1)^{(p - 1) (q - 1)/4}\left( \frac{p}{q}\right) = 1$ be equivalent to $p \equiv \pm \beta^2$ mod $4q$? I've tried just applying Legendre symbol's properties and seeing if something sticks, but got nothing. 
There must be something easy i'm missing, since this is an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four possibilities to consider.

> $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $(\frac{p}{q})=1$

Then $p\equiv \beta^2 \mod q$ and $p\equiv \beta^2 \mod 4$. Therefore $p\equiv \beta^2 \mod 4q$.

Also, $p^*=p$ and so $(\frac{p^*}{q})=1.$

Thus the two expressions agree in this case.

> $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $(\frac{p}{q})=-1$
>
> $p\equiv -1 \mod 4$ and $(\frac{p}{q})=1$
>
> $p\equiv -1 \mod 4$ and $(\frac{p}{q})=-1$

In each of these cases, proceed as in the first case and you should have no difficulty in proving the two expressions always agree. Ask if you get stuck though.

Comment: So why the author introduces $p^*$ if the proof doesn't need it.